# Random value of "Called asynchronously" in Application Insights logs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, azure, asynchronous, azure-application-insights

I'm developing an API (using Web API 2.3) which is consumed by an AngularJS web app.

I've enabled Azure Application Insights, and I noticed that, for the same operation, the same call is either **Called asynchronously = false** or **Called asynchronously = true**.

For example:

[image]

[image]

I did not change anything between these two calls (they're called within a second).

How shall I understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApplicationInsights cannot reliably detect if dependency is sync or async. This feature is removed in the latest SDK and soon will be gone in UI.

Answer (score 0):

An Async call is basically a method that is used to request a method to be executed (Such as retrieving data from a database). The method does not block your API from executing thus the rest of your API can continue executing, up until the request method is done executing which then the program use a "Callback" method. This returns a response which you can then further alter to your means (Such as populating a grid).

Further information can be found at.
http://docs.apigee.com/api-baas/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-calls

Also a main component in an Async call are web servlets. The servlet has primarly two methods. One is GET which by the look of it you are using and POST.  GET is a public method of running a servlet and passing data through means of a URL and POST does everything in the background. Using Async you can use your servlet without disturbing the API. The servlet would usually request whatever you need (Such as retrieving data from a database)

Further information can be found at.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/index.htm

Have a nice day

Comment: Hmm yes thanks, but I think I misexplained my issue. I know what is an asynchronous call, but what I don't understand is why the same calls are considered sometimes async and shortly after, synchronous.